# Star Rating Control which should accept the decimal part also

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, rating

Am Using Visual studio 2010 and coding by C#. Now i want to do a star rating control ie I have some values within 5, not more than that and i want to show the value rated by start based on the rating. Below is the clear scenario.

1. If I get a value 5 then i have to to show all 5 star filled up with some colour.
2. If i get a value 3 then i have to show 3 star which is filled up with some colour and rest stars as empty.
3. If i get the value 3.5 theh i have to show 3 start which is filled up with colour and next 4th star with HALF FILLED and another HALF and one star as empty ie without colour.
4. If i get the value some 4.2 means i have to show 4 starts which is filled with colour completely and the last only 0.2 % should be filled with colour and rest part as empty.

How can i achieve this?? Am using ajax control and i don't want to use jquery please note.

Can any one help me in this??

Thanks

Comment: i Just tried the below thing but its throwing me the exception. In aspx i have added the below code using ajax control <ajax:Rating  ID="Rating1" AutoPostBack="true" OnChanged="OnRatingChanged" runat="server"
    StarCssClass="Star" WaitingStarCssClass="WaitingStar" EmptyStarCssClass="Star"
    FilledStarCssClass="FilledStar" />  AND IN THE CODE BEHIND AT THE PAGE LOAD I JUST PASS THE VALUE TO IT like  Rating1.CurrentRating = 3.5; but its throwing me the exception as its not accepting the decimal part.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is exactly what you want

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Rating/Rating.aspx

Comment: Thanks, Am looking the star should accept the decimal part also like for example if i have a value 3.5 then the 3 and half stars should be colored and rest 1 and half star should be empty.

Comment: i want same solution in WPF i have to use in wpf is there any same solution for wpf...which accept decimal value.?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is this......
[CLICK ME](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-AJAX-Rating-Extender-Control-Database-Example-How-to-save-and-display-Average-Rating-value-from-database.aspx)
Only AJAX and No Jquery used just as you want.

Comment: Thanks, but it should accept the decimal part also. i mean if the value is 3.5 it should show me 3 and half star should be filled with colour and rest 1 and half star should be empty. The link what you have specified its wont sounds so.

Comment: You can show half a star it is possible with that tutorial. Have you downloaded it yet?

Comment: Images of full star have been used in that example you can include image of half a star as well. You should give it a try.

Comment: yes please have a look here. in aspx i have done <ajax:Rating  ID="Rating1" AutoPostBack="true" OnChanged="OnRatingChanged" runat="server"
    StarCssClass="Star" WaitingStarCssClass="WaitingStar" EmptyStarCssClass="Star"
    FilledStarCssClass="FilledStar" />   and in code behind am just passing the value to it like  Rating1.CurrentRating = 3.5; but its throwing me the exception

Comment: If you are getting this control can not be created error then make sure you have replced <cc1: with <ajax: everywhere on that page.

Comment: am sure my tag prefix is ajax in all over the page and more than all i have one and only one ajax control is in my aspx page. to that control in my code behind at page load am just trying to hard code directly the value like  Rating1.CurrentRating = 3.5; which it showing me the exception as i cant pass the decimal value.

Comment: You will have to use 10 half a star images. And then give CurrentRating=7. It will be displayed as 3.5 star. It is a little tricky. add MaxRating="10" at the end. 
FilledStarCssClass="FilledStar" MaxRating="10">